# Is there any python equivalent of haskell's "it" , to get last successful command in REPL

Tags: python, python-3.x, haskell

In haskell ghci, "it" means last successful command, which can be used in next command arbitrarily as per need. Is some thing like this exist in python, not asking for history (reverse-i-search)

Comment: `_` will give you the result of the last line evaluated (that wasn't `None`), in case that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` will give you the result of the last line evaluated (that wasn't `None`).

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov  8 2018, 09:08:57)
[Clang 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2+5
7
>>> _
7
```